# How to increase i/o throughput for faster reading in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a C program who is reading from stdin. And i will test my program to 2GB of data with (4KB of read buffer) with dd command on linux.

I got 565MB/s on 3.20GHz machine. I got lesser in 300MHz machine. Is there any trick to maximize input speed. I have read some proc entry but can get any help. (is it something that i can maximize kernel io buffer size to increase speed?).
Please reply in brief asap.

Beginner in this field.

Comment: You should profile your code to see whether it's I/O or processing that it is determining throughput.

Comment: I have seen my throughput outcome using pv command. (pipe viewer) Is there any way to increase I/O throughput. I have minimized my processing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing your read buffer (currently at 4K) will help speed things up. There is no other relevant tunable that can consistently help you. Reducing context-switches and larger batching of work should be your key method.

Comment: Increase the buffer you give to your read() syscall, Test if you are blocked on the input or not (use strace -T to see if you are blocked for long on the read calls), if yes you need to work on the external stuff (buffering externally, fadvise, etc.), if not, you are still blocked inside your app, consider using a thread to read the data and another thread to process the it. Are you sure you don't have a problem in your output side? Try to write to /dev/null or not write at all to check.

Answer (score 1):

If your 2GB inputs are in continuous blocks on the disk, you can try to set the `fadvise` for the kernel. This will make the prefetch window of the Linux kernel bigger.

Beware that this will only help if accessing your hard drive is the bottleneck.